# Problems wth building Python Image Registration Toolkit

Tags: python, cython, cythonize

I'm having trouble building PIRT (Python Image Registration Toolkit library). I have downloaded from bitbucket using mercurial (`hg clone https://bitbucket.org/almarklein/pirt`). But when I try to build it using `python setup.py` I get the following error:

```
Compiling pirt/splinegrid_.pyx because it changed.
[1/2] Cythonizing pirt/interp/interpolation_.pyx

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

    # Methods
    cdef void calculate_lut(self, spline_type, int N)
    cdef double* get_coef(self, double t) nogil
    cdef double* get_coef_from_index(self, int i)    
    cdef double spline_type_to_id(self, spline_type)
                                ^
------------------------------------------------------------

pirt/interp/interpolation_.pxd:23:33: C method 'spline_type_to_id' is declared but not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 49, in <module>
    extensions = cythonize(extensions)
  File "/home/osboxes/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 877, in cythonize
    cythonize_one(*args)
  File "/home/osboxes/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 997, in cythonize_one
    raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: pirt/interp/interpolation_.pyx
```

I have Cython and visvis already installed (through Anaconda) but building still fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I couldn't find documentation on what exact part of the functions should be declared in `.pxd` files. Thankfully, one can view the existing ones in [`Cython/Includes`](https://github.com/cython/cython/tree/master/Cython/Includes) and draw conclusions.

In short, change the definition in [`pirt/interp/interpolation_.pxd`](https://bitbucket.org/almarklein/pirt/src/849f57b3f0c1a8301a4a8ef57122d81ec4ec7312/pirt/interp/interpolation_.pxd?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#interpolation_.pxd-23) from:

```
cdef double spline_type_to_id(self, spline_type)
```

to:

```
cdef double spline_type_to_id(self, spline_type) except *
```

and run `setup.py` again.